# Using members of an instance assigned inside a "with" block throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I've noticed a really strange behavior in .NET and it took me a little while to figure out what was going on because, to me, it's not intuitive.  Assume I have the following class:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Private Shared people As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Person)

    Class Person
        Public Property FirstName() As String
        Public Property LastName As String

        Public Sub SayMyName()
            MsgBox(FirstName & " " & LastName)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(FirstName As String, LastName As String)
            Me.FirstName = FirstName
            Me.LastName = LastName
        End Sub
    End Class

    Shared Sub Test()
        Dim checkPerson As Person = Nothing

        With checkPerson
            If (Not people.TryGetValue(3, checkPerson)) Then checkPerson = New Person("Bob", "Allen")
            .SayMyName()
        End With
    End Sub

    Shared Sub New()
        people.Add(1, New Person("John", "Doe"))
        people.Add(2, New Person("Jane", "Smith"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I call `TestClass.Test()`, a System.NullReferenceException is thrown by the call to `SayMyName()`.  If I'm debugging, there is no apparent null reference.  I realized eventually that it's because the reference is null when the "with" block starts and it's still being treated as such by the CLR even though the debugger shows that it exists.

Obviously, my sample is simplified for clarity, but in my real code, it's useful to declare the instance way outside the "with" block and then conditionally assign it inside the block (i.e. if it wasn't assigned earlier outside the "With" block).

Does anyone have a reasonable explanation for this?  I know I can easily get around this, but I'm just curious to see what people think or know about this behavior.

Comment: When you write this -- `checkPerson = New Person("Bob", "Allen").SayMyName()`, doesn't it set "checkPerson" to the return value of "SayMyName", ie nothing?  I'm surprised that compiles.

Comment: @McGarnagle -- it's not one line, it's two lines.  ".SayMyName()" is a separate call.

Comment: @McGarnagle The With block makes that a completely separate line of code, and not related to the statement above.  It behaves differently than other languages (like C#) in this respect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`With block`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) works by taking an *expression* and evaluating it *one time*, then allowing you to use that for multiple statements.

In your case, here, when you write this:

```
With checkPerson
    If (Not people.TryGetValue(3, checkPerson)) Then checkPerson = New Person("Bob", "Allen")
    .SayMyName()
End With
```

The *expression* is `checkPerson` on the first line.  This becomes the equivelent of doing:

```
' Evaluate the expression
Dim temp = checkPerson

' Perform statements, substituting as required
If (Not people.TryGetValue(3, checkPerson)) Then checkPerson = New Person("Bob", "Allen")
temp.SayMyName()
```

This behavior is *by design*, and intended to prevent having to evaluate the expresion multiple times if it's expensive, ie:

```
With SomeExpensiveFunctionThatReturnsAnObject()
```

It's documented clearly in the expression section of the [With documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx):

> An expression that evaluates to an object. The expression may be arbitrarily complex and is evaluated only once. The expression can evaluate to any data type, including elementary types.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

The `With` block captures the current value of the expression you pass it, once.  (it stores this value in a compiler-generated hidden variable)

Had it behaved the way you want it to, writing `With SomeSlowFunction()` would call the function again for every line of code in the block.